# Limit of n to the power kn.

Tags: limits

I know that $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1$,  but what is $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{2/n}$ ?

More generally what is $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{k/n}$ where k does not depend on n?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's also $1$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the limit exists.  Denote it $L$.  Then, $\forall k\in\Bbb R$ we have
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{k/n}\\
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n^{1/n}\right)^k\\
L&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}\right)^k\\
L&=1^k\\
L&=1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$a_n=n^{\frac kn}\implies \log(a_n)={\frac kn}\log(n)=k \frac {\log(n)} n \to 0\implies a_n\to 1\,\,\forall k$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\dfrac{f(n)\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0$
as $ n \to \infty$
then

$n^{f(n)/n}
=e^{f(n)\ln(n)/n}
\to e^0
= 1$.

This applies to constant $f(n)$,
$f(n) = n^{1-c}$
for any $c > 0$,
and
$f(n) = n^{1-c}(\ln(n))^m$
for any $c > 0$ and $m > 0$.